# Is there a word that means say something to a dead person?

Tags: word-request

Ok, so I thought about the word pray, but the definitions of prayer seems to indicate that you are talking to God, and not just any deceased person, so is there a word for it? It seems that the verb pray can be used to introduce dialogues, but it can only be used to mean that the person praying is praying to God or a person of worship.

For example:

> The mother ____ to his deceased son "Be well, son. I hope you will
>   find happiness," as she stared into the sky.

Comment: A mother speaks to *her* deceased son. I don’t think English has a word specifically for speaking with the dead. Is she speaking to the son’s dead body that is in her presence or just thinking about him wherever she is?

Comment: @Mixolydian I concur with you. Do you want to give this a formal answer?

Comment: Is there a word for this in your native language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mixolydian Answered this in the comments so the is basicly the same thing as his comment but if this is answered it should get off of the page.

It would just be speaks, there is no English word for speaking to the dead. Here is @Mixolydian's answer

> A mother speaks to her deceased son. I don’t think English has a word specifically for speaking with the dead. Is she speaking to the son’s dead body that is in her presence or just thinking about him wherever she is? – Mixolydian 1 hour ago